# How to select only items in content folder and item datasources using powershell script?

Tags: powershell-extensions

how can I select only content items, items in content folder and Datasources of that items using PowerShell Extension script?

```
  $items = @()
    foreach($baseItem in $listOfPages) {

     if($baseItem.Paths.IsContentItem){
         
        $items += Get-Item $baseItem.Paths.FullPath
        
         foreach($childItem in Get-ChildItem $baseItem.Paths.FullPath -Recurse) {
    
            if($childItem.Paths.FullPath -contains 'Content'{
                
                Write-Host "Child items is content "
                
                $items += $childItem
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Content folder you mean `/sitecore/content` or any folder under an item?

Comment: Yes, I mean content folder under an item only

Answer (score 3):

So the code will be something like this.

```
$items = @()

foreach($baseItem in $listOfPages) 
{
    if($baseItem.Paths.IsContentItem)
    {
        foreach($childItem in Get-ChildItem $baseItem.Paths.FullPath -Recurse) 
        {
            # Need to check that if any child item has the folder name called 'Content'
            if($childItem.Name -contains 'Content') 
            {
                Write-Host "Child items is content"
    
                # Add this item in Array         
                $items += $childItem

                # Add it's child items in Array                 
                $items += Get-ChildItem $childItem.Paths.FullPath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: It works, but what if the child item have the name of item itself the Content?

Comment: So you need to check by the template also along with name. Because usually the content under the item is treated as a Folder template.  And if you have any specific template for the content item then you can check with that. @eratosten123

Comment: @eratosten123 Did it resolve your issue?